# Somar inputs em relatório com mais de uma tabela!

Tags: jquery

Estou gerando um relatório e ele tem várias tabelas. No jQuery tenho que somar 2 inputs de cada tabela, o problema é que ele só soma o da primeira tabela. Tentei usar o `next()`, mas não deu certo.

Segue o código HTML:

```html
<td id=\"tabela\">
<input type=\"text\" id=\"tabelainput\" class=\"janmembros\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"janmembros\" value=\"$row[janmembros]\" disabled>
</td>
<td id=\"tabela\">
<input type=\"text\" id=\"tabelainput\" class=\"janvisitantes\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"janvisitantes\" value=\"$row[janvisitantes]\" disabled>
</td>
<td id=\"tabela3\" class=\"jantotal\">
</td>

<td id=\"tabela\">
<input type=\"text\" id=\"tabelainput\" class=\"janmembros\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"janmembros\" value=\"$row[janmembros]\" disabled>
</td>
<td id=\"tabela\">
<input type=\"text\" id=\"tabelainput\" class=\"janvisitantes\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"janvisitantes\" value=\"$row[janvisitantes]\" disabled>
</td>
<td id=\"tabela3\" class=\"jantotal\">
</td>

<td id=\"tabela\">
<input type=\"text\" id=\"tabelainput\" class=\"janmembros\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"janmembros\" value=\"$row[janmembros]\" disabled>
</td>
<td id=\"tabela\">
<input type=\"text\" id=\"tabelainput\" class=\"janvisitantes\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"janvisitantes\" value=\"$row[janvisitantes]\" disabled>
</td>
<td id=\"tabela3\" class=\"jantotal\">
</td>
```

jQuery:

```js
if ( $( ".janmembros" ).val().length >= 1 && $( ".janvisitantes" ).val().length >= 1 )
{
$( ".jantotal" ).html( parseInt($( ".janmembros" ).val()) + parseInt($( ".janvisitantes" ).val()) );
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfgF5/)

Comment: Tens vários elementos na página com o mesmo ID, o jQuery ao localizar elementos por ID, só procura um elemento, pelo que, só o primeiro é somado... `ID` é um identificador único, deverás fazer uso de `class` ou rectificar esses ID's para não se repetirem.

Comment: @Zuul, mas no jquery eu estou usando classes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dado que conténs vários elementos a serem localizados para realizar a operação de somar valores e apresentar o resultado, podes fazer uso da função de iteração [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) do jQuery que te vai permitir por cada grupo de elementos localizados, realizar determinada operação sobre os mesmos:

[Exemplo a Funcionar no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/6g6Wd/)

```
// se estão presentes e não estão vazios
if ( $( ".janmembros" ).val() != '' && $( ".janvisitantes" ).val() != '' )
{

    // por cada tabela encontrada
    $('table').each(function() {

        /* coloca em cache o objecto referente à tabela
         * e trabalha com os elementos dentro da mesma
         */
        var $this = $(this),                                             // cache da <table>
            janmembros = parseInt($this.find( ".janmembros" ).val()),
            janvisitantes = parseInt($this.find( ".janvisitantes" ).val());

        // soma e enviar para o destino
        $this.find( ".jantotal" ).html( janmembros+janvisitantes ); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Ótimo, era isso que eu precisava!!!